A Ben Ger who converted before his mother did - can he become a Dayan?
Shalom,
On this topic (Can a convert serve as a dayan?), I saw this answer:

" [A convert can ] Force a judgment even on a Yisrael if the converts mother or father was born of a Yisrael"

This answer was based on Shulchan Aruch, Choshen Misphat 7:1
However, it seems in that case it is only a Jew whose father is Israel and mother is a convert or whose mother is Israel and father is a convert.
So we are not talking about a convert with a jewish father but a Ben Guer. (If his father is Israel and her mother a convert)
So what applies in  this case (does this apply to a son of an Israel and a non-jewish mother, who converts before his mother?)

I just reddited it

If this fellow himself converted, he is a convert and can't execute the full functions of a "blue-blooded" Jewish judge.
Say in 2004 a non-Jewish woman gives birth. Then in August 2024, the 20-year-old son converts. It doesn't matter if his mother converted in July 2024 or September 2024 -- this fellow is still halachically a convert.
Let's look at the original Hebrew again from Choshen Mishpat 7:1:

ב"ד של ג' שהיה אחד מהם גר ה"ז פסול לדון לישראל אא"כ היתה אמו (או אביו) (מרדכי בשם תוס' פ"ב מ"ח) מישראל


A Beit Din in which one is a convert may not judge a Yisrael; rather it must be that his mother (or father) was from Yisrael.

I.e. Jewish stock in there someplace. That doesn't mean "as of today", it means "as of the day he was born."

Yes, but what if the convert's father was Israeli at birth and his mother was non-Jewish?
